# passing the USER id into another page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass the id of the user who is logged into the " add new company " page so when he adds a new company it will have that user's id ... this is the controller i am using :

```
class UserController extends Controller{

public function dashboard()
{
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>User::select('id','name','last_name')->where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser'))->first()];

    return view('Dashboard.dashboard' ,$data);
}



public function user_add($id)
{
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>User::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser'))->first()];
    $userid = User::find($id);

    $Activities = activities::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    $Sous_Categories = sous_categories::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    $Secteurs = secteurs::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    return view('Dashboard.add_entrepUser',$data ,['Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories ,  'Activities'=> $Activities]);
}



public function logout(){    // user logout
    if(session()->has('LoggedUser'))
    {
        session()->pull('LoggedUser');
        return redirect('/');
    }
}


public function store_company(Request $request)
{


      $company = new entreprise;

      $company->RS = $request->RS;
      $company->adresse = $request->adresse;
      $company->Fax = $request->Fax;
      $company->Tel1 = $request->Tel1;
      $company->Tel2 = $request->Tel2;
      $company->mail = $request->mail;
      $company->Siteweb = $request->Siteweb;
      $company->Descp = $request->Descp;
      $company->idact = $request->activity;
      $company->idSousCat = $request->sub_category;
      $company->secteurs_id = $request->secteur;
      $company->lan = $request->lan;
      $company->lng = $request->lng;
      $company->accepted = 0;
      $company->active = 0;
      $company->user_id = $request->id;

      $company->save();

      return redirect('Dashboard.dashboard');

}   }
```

and this is the code that sends me too the adding of new company :

```
<div class="dashboard_container">
<!-- Header -->
<header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="logo"> <a href="/"><img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/logo.png')}}" alt="image"/></a> </div>
            <div id="dashboard-responsive-nav-trigger"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></div>
          </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
                <div class="user_nav ml-auto">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <span id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/user.png')}}" alt="img">
                      </span>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>{{ $LoggedUserInfo['name']}} {{ $LoggedUserInfo['last_name']}}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>                   
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="submit_listing">
                    <a href="{{ route('add_company') }}" class="btn outline-btn"><i class="fa  fa-plus-circle"></i> Ajouter </a>
                 </div>
                 
            </div>
         </div>   
    </nav>
</header>
```

i have no clue what should i be doing ... if someone has some ideas please !

Comment: `auth()->id()` will return the id of the currently logged in user

Comment: @brombeer where should i put it please ?

Comment: You could/should `dd(auth()->id())` just to make sure that is the correct id. Then most likely in `$company->user_id = $request->id` instead of `$request->id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try this

```
public function dashboard()
{  $id = auth()->user()->id;
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>User::select('id','name','last_name')->where('id' , '=' ,  $id)->first()];
 

    return view('Dashboard.dashboard' ,$data);
}

public function user_add($id)
{
$id = auth()->user()->id;
$data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>User::where('id' , '=' , $id))->first()];
   
    $userid = User::find($id);

    $Activities = activities::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    $Sous_Categories = sous_categories::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    $Secteurs = secteurs::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    return view('Dashboard.add_entrepUser',$data ,['Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories ,  'Activities'=> $Activities]);
}
```